# Dynamically create configured components ( flexipages )

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have a custom community app with our own custom Application component ( .app ) as frame

But we really would like to take advantage of Lightning page builder

We tried :

1. `<flexipage:page flexipageDeveloperName="MyCustomConfiguredHomePage">`
   this component is used by SFDC to instanciate configured components
   Problem: this is not a public component
2. `<force:recordView id="idOfADummyObjectAssociatedToAFlexipage" >`
   But is always displays the list of fields ( classic layout ) and not the "Lightning Record Page"

My questions is simple :
**- Is there any way (hacking or not) to include a configured component ( flexipage ) from a custom component , using $A.createComponent() ?**

This would really save us, and the alternative is to build our own configuration tool ... and as it is already existing in SFDC, we clearly don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce tells me that they speak about it for a while, but that it is not planned.

Seems like we'll have to :

- read flexipage metadatas to feed some custom table with components and their positions in templates
- then create our own flexipage component who will make a createComponent with the custom template, then call createComponent for each region ( that must not be that hard )

If someone has the same need and is interested to share the workload of such development, please contact me

Comment: did you have a chance to do some work on it?

Comment: It was some time ago... I don't remember how but I did otherwise ^^
But with all evolutions on Lightning , maybe there has been some evolutions since :)

Comment: from what I know it's still not possible to create templating components, like Tabs that you can afterwards customize in App Builder